# Finding deviations from trend slope based on given threshold

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, signal-processing, data-analysis

I have time series that goes like this:

```
Date,val
02/06/1980,0.9866
03/06/1980,0.9859
04/06/1980,0.9657
05/06/1980,0.9859
06/06/1980,0.9864
09/06/1980,0.9871
10/06/1980,0.9877
11/06/1980,0.9885
12/06/1980,0.9895
13/06/1980,0.9905
16/06/1980,0.9921
17/06/1980,0.9933
18/06/1980,0.9945
19/06/1980,0.9958
20/06/1980,0.9971
23/06/1980,0.9989
24/06/1980,1.0244
25/06/1980,1.0029
26/06/1980,1.005
27/06/1980,1.0068
30/06/1980,1.0082
01/07/1980,1.0096
02/07/1980,1.011
03/07/1980,1.0127
07/07/1980,1.0149
08/07/1980,1.0168
09/07/1980,1.0185
10/07/1980,1.0198
11/07/1980,1.0213
14/07/1980,1.0232
15/07/1980,1.025
16/07/1980,1.027
17/07/1980,1.0292
18/07/1980,1.0316
21/07/1980,1.0341
22/07/1980,1.0361
23/07/1980,1.038
24/07/1980,1.0399
25/07/1980,1.0415
28/07/1980,1.0431
29/07/1980,1.0448
30/07/1980,1.0464
31/07/1980,1.0481
01/08/1980,1.0497
04/08/1980,1.0512
05/08/1980,1.0528
06/08/1980,1.0543
07/08/1980,1.0561
08/08/1980,1.0582
11/08/1980,1.0604
12/08/1980,1.0623
13/08/1980,1.0641
14/08/1980,1.0661
15/08/1980,1.0681
18/08/1980,1.0698
19/08/1980,1.0714
20/08/1980,1.0732
21/08/1980,1.0749
22/08/1980,1.0764
25/08/1980,1.0778
26/08/1980,1.079
```

Value column is the product of 63 day moving average divided by 252 day moving average. I'd like to identify time periods in which the slope rises by 5% (or more) from the recent bottom and periods where slope falls by 5% (or more) from the recent top. The result should be more or less like this below:

[image]

Is there any way- other than iterating through the data frame and locating bottoms/tops and do one by one comparison? I find it nontrivial and hard to imagine, how this should look like.

Comment: If the movement is between -5 and + 5, what should happen? I think we could use `groupby` and `cumsum` with `pct_change`. But I need to know exactly what is the division rule in itervalos to create a code

Comment: I would suggest a solution that uses discrete derivative

Comment: Thank you. Essentially, you would like to mark the time periods when slopes rises by more than 5% from recent bottom as risk_on = 1, when falls risk_off = 1, when the condition is not met, both risk zones are equal to 0, so you're in neutral zone.

Comment: @cristianhantig thank you. Do you know by any chance particular literature or similar problem resolved with the use of discrete derivative?

Comment: @krakowi i don't know any particular literature, it just came into my mind. Also, i would compute the distribution of the slopes and select the slopes above some percentile (let's say 95)

Comment: @cristianhantig that was one of the ideas, but the tricky part is that it has to always refer to local maximums.

Comment: @krakowi sorry, i thought that you re interested only on steep slopes